# How to enable browser spell check in CKEditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor

Supposedly CKEditor has built-in spell check, but I've never seen it work (not even on their live demo site) and so in CKEditor 3 I added the following to the config function to enable browser spell check and enable the browser context menu:

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
config.removePlugins = 'scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in CKEditor 4.

How can I enable the browser spell checker and context menu in CKEditor 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the [CKEditor Builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) and removing SCAYT plugin, then putting the code in my question in the config function works.

Answer (score 6):

It happens because `contextmenu` plugin is required by other plugins:

`Plugin "contextmenu" cannot be removed from the plugins list, because it's required by "liststyle" and "tabletools" plugin.`

But actially spellcheck should work, but since the `Context Menu` plugin is enabled, it is necessary to hold the `Ctrl` key when right-clicking misspelled words to see their suggestions.

Refer CKEditor [Spell Checking documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_spellcheck)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Average (non geek) users get confused easily. I proposed an improvement: The context menu of ckeditor could provide a help text to reveal the magic ctrl+right-click solution. Here is the issue: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/981

Comment: A good note here also - The order the plugins are removed matters... I was getting a similar required by x plugin. Modifying the removePlugins to be config.removePlugins = 'scayt,tableselection,tabletools,contextmenu'; got my setup to work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable browsers spelling checker you should add following configuration:

```
config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,tabletools,scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought a summary of all helpful answers might help.

### Permanent

```js
// Prevent CKEditor disabling a browser's native spell checking feature
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
    
// Disable CKEditor's SpellCheckAsYouType plugin;
// Disable CKEditor's contextmenu plugin
config.removePlugins = 'scayt,contextmenu';
```

### Partial, temporary

If you need CKEditor's `contextmenu` plugin (for use with another plugin) your user's will be required to hold the `Ctrl` key to temporarily disable CKEditor's `contextmenu` plugin and access the browser's native spell checking feature, via the browser's usual context menu, for each and every word they want to adjust.

```js
// Prevent CKEditor disabling a browser's native spell checking feature
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
    
// Disable CKEditor's SpellCheckAsYouType plugin;
// Disable CKEditor's contextmenu plugin
config.removePlugins = 'scayt';
```

Answer (score -2):

Please enable the scayt in toolbar placed in config.js. Please make sure you have included 'Scayt' if you rendered the editor with custom toolbar.

Comment: Scayt != browser spell checker